# Xuggler MediaWriter Operation Not Permitted Issue

Tags: java, xuggler

I keep getting an exception when I close an IMediaWriter doing a 
simple transcode. 
The exception is "java.lang.RuntimeException: error Operation not 
permitted, failed to write trailer to test.mp3" 
I get this whenever I call IMediaWriter.close(),Any ideas why I would be getting this for a simple transcoding? 
Here's the sample code:

```
IMediaReader reader = null; 
    IMediaWriter writer = null; 
    try { 
        reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("test.wav"); 
        writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("test.mp3", reader); 
        reader.addListener(writer); 
        while (reader.readPacket() == null) ; 
        reader.close(); 
        writer.close(); 
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked os file permissions?

Comment: Make the application hang right before `writer.close()`, either by using a break point or an eternal loop. Then manually copy `test.mp3` and try playing this new file using a couple of different software audio players. Is there any audio data there? -- In other words, is the only problem closing the writer?

Answer (score 2):

This will work surely because I was facing same problem.  Thank you.  If You want more clarification please ask...

```
IMediaReader reader = null; 
    IMediaWriter writer = null; 
    try { 
        reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("sijo.mp4"); 
        writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("Thomas.flv", reader); 
        reader.addListener(writer); 
        while (reader.readPacket() == null) ; 
        //Should IMediaReader automatically call close(), only if ERROR_EOF (End of File) is returned from readPacket().
        reader.setCloseOnEofOnly(false); 
        //If false the media data will be left in the order in which it is presented to the IMediaWriter.
        //If true IMediaWriter will buffer media data in time stamp order, and only write out data when it has at least one same time or later packet from all streams.
        writer.setForceInterleave(false);
        System.out.println("closed...");
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```